# firestore Error: Argument "documentPath" must point to a document

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I build react native app with firebase/firestore and I get the error

```
Error: Argument "documentPath" must point to a document.
```

when I write this line

```
    var userStatusFirestoreRef = firebase.firestore().doc('/status/' + uid);
```

all code

```
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData().then((user) => {
    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    var userStatusFirestoreRef = firebase.firestore().doc('/status/' + uid);
});
```

Comment: What's the value of `uid` when you console.log it?

Comment: the value is my uid 'Nqc413xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Comment: you may want to try `firebase.firestore().collection('status').doc(uid)`. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: yes, that way also good. thanks

Comment: It looks like we cannot create documents at root level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should chain the `collection()` and `doc()` methods for each segment of the firestore path, example:

`firebase.firestore().collection('status').doc(uid)`

You can chain these as far as your subcollections and subdocuments go.

`firebase.firestore().collection('status').doc(uid).collection('messages').doc('messageId')`

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE : now you can't put a forward slash '/' in a document's name, it throws the error:

> firebase.firestore().collection().doc(*) 'document path' must point a docment

Answer (score 3):

I found the error,
it should be

```
    var userStatusFirestoreRef = firebase.firestore().doc('status/' + uid);
```

with one '/' at the end of 'status/'

Answer (score 0):

sometime it's happened because we forget to write **collection()** reference